# Django-Oscar override non-abstract model: ShippingEventQuantity

Tags: django-models, django-oscar

I want to add a field in the ShippingEventQuantity model of the order app in django-oscar. But this model is not abstract and hence I am struggling to find a way to override it.

I tried the following to try to override this model. Using this code, I get the error, when I run makemigrations command:

```
class SShippingEventQuantity(ShippingEventQuantity):
    replacement = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'order'
        verbose_name = _("Shipping Event Quantity")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Shipping Event Quantities")
        unique_together = ('event', 'line', 'replacement')

Errors:
order.SShippingEventQuantity: (models.E016) 'unique_together' refers to field 'event' which is not local to model 'SShippingEventQuantity'.
HINT: This issue may be caused by multi-table inheritance.
order.SShippingEventQuantity: (models.E016) 'unique_together' refers to field 'line' which is not local to model 'SShippingEventQuantity'.
HINT: This issue may be caused by multi-table inheritance.
```

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. Whilst Oscar tries to be flexible, not everything is overriable.

As you noted, `order.abstract_models.ShippingEventQuantity` is not an abstract model, so Oscar doesn't support overriding it via the usual means, this is probably because it is being used as a through model.

I'd suggest you ask a new question about how to best achieve your end goal, there are usually multiple approaches to change Oscar's behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. I'll think of another way to implement my requirements.